# IOS app in another virtual device

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing a IOS app and I need to run it at a different virtual device.

**Is there a way to export the .ipa file, and run it at another simulator (another machine)?**

If necessary, I can include the other virtual device (or machine) in my Provisioning Team.   **I don't know if it is possible.**

PS: I just need to run the app in another virtual device, this thirdy guy will not program. It will just for understand the usability and user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if you have access to the original source code, partly for obvious security/theft concerns, but also because compiled .ipa files are built for ARM64, and the simulator runs x86_64 architecture.

The only way to run it in another simulator is to install Xcode on the other machine, clone your repo, and run it in the simulator directly.

The only two other things I can suggest are:

1. https://appetize.io/, which does a fair to middling job of emulating iOS apps in the browser
2. Package and compile your app and distribute it using TestFlight or [ad-hoc OTA](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) to the people demoing your app